# NullPointer Exception while updating UI from AsyncTask is Finished

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am trying to update the Main Thread UI after the `Async` is executed. I've tried to update it via `onPostExecute` and getting `NullPointerException` .

Here is my class

```
public class UncheckGuestArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<UncheckGuestObj> {
    private final Activity thisContext;
    private ArrayList<UncheckGuestObj> guest = new ArrayList<UncheckGuestObj>();

    // String event_id;
    private String guest_id;

    // TODO to ask about the checkin
    static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView guestName;
        public TextView guestEmail;
        public Button btnCheckIn;
    }

    public ViewHolder holder;

    private ViewHolder getHolder(View v) {
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.guestName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tx_guest_name);
        holder.guestEmail = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tx_guest_email);
        holder.btnCheckIn = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btnCheckIn);
        return holder;
    }

    public UncheckGuestArrayAdapter(Activity context,
            ArrayList<UncheckGuestObj> objects) {
        super(context, R.layout.row_guest_list, objects);
        this.thisContext = context;
        this.guest = objects;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        View vi = convertView;
        if (vi == null || vi.getTag() == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) thisContext
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_guest_list, null);
            holder = getHolder(vi);
            vi.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();
        }

        holder.guestName.setText(guest.get(position).guestName);
        holder.guestEmail.setText(guest.get(position).guestEmail);
        holder.btnCheckIn.setText("Check In");
        // holder.btnCheckIn.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);

        holder.btnCheckIn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("you clicked", "the item at [" + position + "] position");
                guest_id = guest.get(position).guestId;
                new CheckInAsync().execute();
            }
        });

        return vi;
    }

    // Check In Async Task for executing the POST Request
    public class CheckInAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(3000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            try {

                URI uri = new URI(Constants.BASE_URL + "/events/"
                        + GuestListActivity.event_id + "/guests/" + guest_id);
                Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), uri.toString());
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(uri);

                // Add your data
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(
                        2);
                // nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sk", SharePref
                // .getInstance(GetEventList.this).getSessionKey()));
                Context mContext = null;
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sk", SharePref
                        .getInstance(mContext).getSessionKey()));
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                int response_code = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                // HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                Log.i("response code", "" + response_code);

                if (response_code == 201) {
                    Log.e("checkin status", "Checkin done");
                }

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            holder.btnCheckIn.setText(R.string.heavy_check_mark);
            holder.btnCheckIn.setBackgroundColor(Color.MAGENTA);
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Checked In!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    }
}
```

And the exception is

```
08-23 18:56:16.192: E/AndroidRuntime(11077): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-23 18:56:16.192: E/AndroidRuntime(11077): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-23 18:56:16.192: E/AndroidRuntime(11077):    at com.example.example.adaptor.UncheckGuestArrayAdapter$CheckInAsync.onPostExecute(UncheckGuestArrayAdapter.java:166)
08-23 18:56:16.192: E/AndroidRuntime(11077):    at com.example.example.UncheckGuestArrayAdapter$CheckInAsync.onPostExecute(UncheckGuestArrayAdapter.java:1)
08-23 18:56:16.192: E/AndroidRuntime(11077):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
08-23 18:56:16.192: E/AndroidRuntime(11077):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
```

Line no. 166 is line in `onPostExecute`

```
        holder.btnCheckIn.setText(R.string.heavy_check_mark);
        holder.btnCheckIn.setBackgroundColor(Color.MAGENTA);
```

What am I doing wrongly ?

Comment: There is a fundamental problem in your approach. Views are re-used to display different items if your list can not show all items at once. If you store a reference to the view(-holder) and uncheck it later you can no longer be sure that it still belongs to the item it did when you started your task.

Comment: What should be the right approach ?

Comment: in `onPostExecute` do something like `guest.setChecked()`, `Adapter#notifyDatasetChanged()` and let your adapter re-build the views with updated (checked) status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Holder object cannot be a member because it corresponds to one single item. And you are not assigning the member value, instead the local ViewHolder is asigned. Here is how it should work. Remove the ViewHolder member,

<strike>public ViewHolder holder;</strike>

and

```
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        // ...
        // copy from original post
        // ...

        holder.btnCheckIn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("you clicked", "the item at [" + position + "] position");
                guest_id = guest.get(position).guestId;
                new CheckInAsync(holder).execute();
            }
        });

        return vi;
    }

    // Check In Async Task for executing the POST Request
    public final class CheckInAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
        private final ViewHolder holder;

        CheckInAsync(ViewHolder holder) {
            this.holder = holder;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
              // copy from original post
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            this.mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            this.holder.btnCheckIn.setText(R.string.heavy_check_mark);
            this.holder.btnCheckIn.setBackgroundColor(Color.MAGENTA);
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Checked In!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think for your ProgressDialog null and async onPreExecute method override implement and solve for your excepiton,

```
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(YourActivityName.this, "wait", "loading");
    }
```

Comment: You will Debug for your code and fetch the exception and will be solved

Answer (score 1):

Try the below

```
   ViewHolder holder;
    if (vi == null || vi.getTag() == null) {
       holder = new ViewHolder();
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) thisContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_guest_list, null); 
        holder.guestName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tx_guest_name);
        holder.guestEmail = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tx_guest_email);
        holder.btnCheckIn = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btnCheckIn);
        holder = getHolder(vi);
        vi.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();
    }
    .....
```

Also you need to follow Doctoror Drive suggestion

You do not have reference to the view's. So when you try to update the views in `onPostExecute` you get `NullPointerException`.

```
    holder.btnCheckIn.setText(R.string.heavy_check_mark);
    holder.btnCheckIn.setBackgroundColor(Color.MAGENTA);
```

Comment: Actually he populated his holder views. See getHolder() method in OP. There is no error out there, just seems like uncommon approach.